# After I update to MacOs Catalina MAMP stop working

Tags: mamp, macos-catalina

I have a folder on my Desktop named work where I keep all my php projects. I use MAMP and all projects are set to work on virtual hosts, for example, if I have a project named test I access this project on this URL http://test.dev.

Everything went ok until I updated to *macOS Catalina* when I started to have this error.

> (1)Operation not permitted: Can't open directory for index: `/Users/username/Desktop/work/php/development/projectname`.

I set the permissions to the work folder and all subfolders to be read & write for my user and staff group, I tried all the terminal permission

```
commands: chmod 777, 755, etc.
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution that worked for you? I just made the upgrade to Catalina and I thought since MAMP 5.5 supports Catalina it would work

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem like you, and I spent many days to solve it by doing:

stop MAMP, then open terminal and type

`sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/startApache.sh -> then Enter`

and then **type your admin password** to give apache full privileges to start apache. (this way can let MAMP read any files on your Mac, include external drives)

now you can open MAMP and see that Apache is started, then click Start on MAMP app to start MySql too.

Comment: This worked for me! However adding both `apachectl` and `httpd` to "Full Disk Access" in system preferences made no difference. I'm surprised that this action didn't have the same basic result as the sudo command.

Comment: However, this does not start the MySQL server. Can I do that too in the terminal?

Comment: @stack-delay : yes, there is a file "startMysql.sh" stay in the same folder with startApache.sh, /Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh. Or you just need to click Start on MAMP app, MAMP will start mysql and keep apache running.

Answer (score 4):

I've solved doing the following operations:

0. Quit MAMP and all the applications that are using mySql and Apache Server (stop all the instances)
1. Go to System Preferences, Systema & Privacy, Full Disk Access Tab
2. Click "add" and go to /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin and add apachectl
3. Run this command from the terminal: `sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/startApache.sh\`
4. Open MAMP and press the Start Servers button

now you should be able to start your localhost app

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to wrong permission given by the new MacOS Catalina permission manager. A possible way to solve this issue is to check if the folder in which the project is stored can be accessed by your Application.

To do this you have to:

- Go to System Preferences
- Go to System & Privacy
- Go to Files and Folders
- Be sure that the folder of your project is checked in the subsection concerning your Application

I hope this could solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did that but unfortunately the error did not disappear. I tried to give full disk access to MAMP application and the error persists.

Comment: Is there any reason why I don’t see any mamp settings under files and folders? I have it under full access yet nothing in the files and folders. Strangely enough, on a coworkers computer, he has the settings. We both run the same Mac OS version and mamp version. Problem is, I need to be able to check off network volumes but it doesn’t appear on mine.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to the steps below I added Full disk access to MAMP under the Security and Privacy Folder.

The steps I did after:

1. Stop MAMP
2. Open terminal
3. Then type: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/startApache.sh`
4. Start MAMP

Incase it wont work, try on the terminal: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/stopApache.sh` and then `/Applications/MAMP/bin/startApache.sh`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with XAMPP. Apache just lost access to my external drive, which I included via a symlink. Even giving "Full Disk Access" to the httpd webserver didn't help.

The final solution was to start Apache with the sudo command:

```
sudo Applications/XAMPP/bin/apachectl start
```

did the job for me. Please note that

```
sudo apachectl start
```

would start the Apache that comes with macOS and thus wouldn't be used with XAMPP (and MAMP as well, I guess).